# Can't fit text to image with ImageMagick

Tags: graphics, fonts, imagemagick

I need to fit my text to image. My image have different sizes so i can't set constant pointsize.

My command looks something like this

```
convert 
    -fill white
    -font Winter Calligraphy
    -size `${options.width}x${options.height}`
    label: KJHGFD
    test.gif
```

on output you can see cropped part on top of picture.

Output:
[image: output image]

- I have problem only with this fonts, other fonts works great.
- I tried to add white border on top. Unfortunately, this only moved the damaged text to bottom.
- I can't change area size.
- Text must fill as much space as possible.
- I need to use Winter Calligraphy font

Comment: Have you tried the `caption:` protocol instead of `label:`? I believe the `caption:` coder will attempt to reduce the point size to fit the canvas.

Comment: I try, and nothing has changed.

Comment: Your quoting is quite wrong! Are you on Windows or macOS or Linux?

Comment: I'm on linux ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly kludgy way of getting the result you want. Here are the steps:

- First, use `caption:` to get **ImageMagick** to tell you the pointsize it would use to fill your text box and extract that info
- Create a canvas twice as wide and twice as tall as the one you really want and draw your text in the middle of that - it is bound to fit!
- Now trim away the extraneous background around the text so you have the absolute minimum bounding box to contain the text
- Resize the result to your desired size.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Width, height and text
w=600
h=150
text="KJHGFD"

# Get pointsize ImageMagick thinks is good
pointsize=$(convert -gravity center -background black -fill white -size ${w}x${h} \
    -font "Winter Calligraphy.ttf" caption:"$text" -format "%[caption:pointsize]" info:)

echo ImageMagick likes pointsize: $pointsize

# So draw text in that size on larger canvas, trim to bounds of letters and resize to desired size
wb=$((w*2))
hb=$((h*2))
convert -gravity center -fill white -size ${wb}x${hb} xc:black \
    -font "Winter Calligraphy.ttf" -pointsize $pointsize -annotate 0 "$text" \
    -trim +repage -resize ${w}x${h}\! result.png
```

[image]

Comment: I will check it tomorrow. Looks great!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in ImageMagick 6.9.10.97 Q16 Mac OSX. I have added `-background white -fill black -gravity center` to your command.

```
convert -background white -fill black -font "/library/fonts/Winter Calligraphy.ttf" -size 569x196 -gravity center label:KJHGFD test.gif
```

[image]

Comment: Look on the K letter on the left. It's cropped.

Can u check it with smaller height? Then you will probably receive this bug (same as my example).

Comment: Some fonts have bad metrics. It is possible this is the case. If you want to pursue it further, I suggest you post on the Imagemagck discourse server bugs form at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/