# Text width in Pillow

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library

I am generating a large number of text images using Pillow (PNG files containing nothing but text). These images should all be of the same, known width. I don’t see any way to determine text width from Pillow, or to direct Pillow to make text fill a specified number of pixels.

Is there a straightforward solution to this?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887152/2836621 If you could be more specific you will probably get a better solution, maybe using **ImageMagick** or **wand**.

Comment: See here too https://stackoverflow.com/a/60576212/2836621